# nth-child with a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF to post WP posts on a page. But I to be able to control certain CSS properties using nth:child selectors. Heres the PHP which displays every thing fine.  Problem is (I'm assuming) that the "foreach" item is making the nth:child not work, because the are not siblings?

```
<div class="row">

<?php
        $posts = get_field('projects');
            if ( $posts ) {
                foreach ( $posts as $post ): ?>
            <div class="col-xl-6 no-space">
            <?php
                    setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <div class="project__wrap">
                      <div class="project__project"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                        <div class="project__description__list col-xl-6"><div class="project-content"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php echo get_the_title() ; ?></h2><p><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 15 ) ); ?></p></a></div>

            <div class="heart"><?php 
                $image = get_field('heart_icon');
                if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

                        </div> <!-- .project__description__list -->
                    </div> <!-- .project__wrap -->

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
           </div>
                <?php endforeach;
                }   
                ?>
```

```
div.project-content:nth-child(odd) {
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

div.project-content:nth-child(even) {
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Apply your nth to the parent and then match on the inner child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is, `project-content` is always the first child of it's container (`project__description__list`). What you want is this for `.col-xl-6.no-space`. But this would be very ambiguous, so I would suggest, to add another class to this div - i.e. `project-row-item`.

```
<div class="col-xl-6 no-space project-row-item">
```

doing so, you could change your css like this

```
.project-row-item:nth-child(odd) div.project-content {
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.project-row-item:nth-child(even) div.project-content {
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    $posts = get_field('projects');
 if ( $posts ) {
 $i=0; $k; $class='';
     foreach ( $posts as $post ): 
        $k= $i%2; 
        if($k==0){ $class='even'; } else { $class='odd'; }?>
        <div class="col-xl-6 no-space">
            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <div class="project__wrap">
                  <div class="project__project"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                    <div class="project__description__list col-xl-6"><div class="project-content <?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php echo get_the_title() ; ?></h2><p><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 15 ) ); ?></p></a></div>
                    <div class="heart"><?php  $image = get_field('heart_icon');
                        if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div> <!-- .project__description__list -->
                </div> <!-- .project__wrap -->
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; }   ?>
```

Now you could change your style as :

```
div.project-content.odd {
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

div.project-content.even {
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```